# Linqpad and Log4net

Tags: log4net, linqpad

I have linqpad referencing one of my own assemblies which uses log4net. When linqpad calls my assembly method I am setting my log4net logging levels to ERROR yet I see debug level messages from my assembly showing up in the linqpad results area.

Anybody know what causes this? Does Linqpad use log4net itself or have any special behavior with log4net?

Answer (score 2):

LINQPad uses SharpDevelop which has a dependency on log4net, but this is kept pretty well isolated to the UI domain and shouldn't have any effect on your queries.

How are you configuring log4net? Is it programmatically or via an application config file? If it's the latter, the application config file should be named linqpad.config in order to be picked up by your queries.

Comment: +1, hey Joe, just bought LINQPad Premium. Love your work, keep it up! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with my configuration not being picked up. Creating a separate `Linqpad.config` (*not* editing LINQPad's own!) is the key bit of info I was missing - thanks Joe. **Fantastic** app by the way!